# error: passing ‘const Flacon’ as ‘this’ argument discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]

Tags: c++

I have this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

class Flacon
{
private:
  string nom;
  double volume;
  double pH;

public:
    Flacon(string nom, double volume, double pH): nom(nom), volume(volume), pH(pH) {}
    ostream& etiquette(ostream&);
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream&,const Flacon &);   
};

ostream& Flacon::etiquette(ostream& sortie){
    sortie << nom << " : " << volume << " ml, pH " << pH;
    return sortie;}

ostream& operator<<(ostream& o,const Flacon & f){
    o=f.etiquette(o);
    return o;
}
```

And the error of the title at line 26:

```
o=f.etiquette(o);
```

There are also another error at the same line:

```
error: use of deleted function ‘std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator=(const std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]’
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first error is because `f` has type `const Flacon &` but `etiquette` has not been declared `const`. You cannot use a const object to call a non-const method. Change this

```
ostream& etiquette(ostream&);
```

to this

```
ostream& etiquette(ostream&) const;
```

And this

```
ostream& Flacon::etiquette(ostream& sortie){
```

to this

```
ostream& Flacon::etiquette(ostream& sortie) const {
```

The second error is because stream objects are not assignable, but you don't need to assign it, just change this

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& o,const Flacon & f){
    o=f.etiquette(o);
    return o;
}
```

to this

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& o,const Flacon & f) {
    f.etiquette(o);
    return o;
}
```